# How to create an app with no GUI but still canuse components

Tags: delphi-xe2

How is it possible to write an application with no gui, but I still want to use the the components?

My task is to go through a SQL database and then do stuff and the write to the eventlog.

Br
Valnurat

Comment: No that will not be my question. My question will be where should I pick the Application with no GUI in the "New Items".

Comment: I only see "Console Application" but that is a "dos app", right?

Comment: No, it's a Windows console application. You don't have to create a console application, though; just remove the `{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}` from the console application code, and it's a non-GUI application.

Answer (score 1):

You should use a `TDataModule`. You can put non-visual components on it at design-time, assign their properties and event handlers as needed, etc.

You can create a VCL Forms project, remove the default `MainForm`, and then instantiate the DM in your code or set the DM to be auto-created, either will work.

Answer (score 1):

@Remy's answer  is probably the easiest, but as an alternative you can also just change the `APPTYPE` directive in a console application from `CONSOLE` to `GUI`, and create your components at runtime in code.

(Note that despite what it says, the `GUI` in that directive does NOT mean "display a graphic user interface"; it means "don't output to the console".)

Here's an example that just copies a test file into another file with the `.bak` extension, with no user interface at all. If you run it from the IDE, it will simply pause for an instant and then return; checking the destination folder will show you that both files exist, meaning it worked. Make sure, of course, that you change the filename to something that actually exists on your system first. :-)

NOTE: All exception handling intentionally left out for clarity. Of course, there should be `try..except` blocks in actual code; there's no need for `try..finally` resource protection here because the app is exiting immediately. **It's a demo app, not production level code.**

```
program Project1;

{$APPTYPE GUI}

uses
  System.SysUtils, Classes;

var
  InStream, OutStream: TFileStream;
const
  InFile = 'E:\TempFiles\TestFile.txt';

var
  OutFile: string;

begin
  OutFile := ChangeFileExt(InFile, '.bak'); 

  InStream := TFileStream.Create(InFile, fmOpenRead);
  OutStream := TFileStream.Create(OutFile, fmCreate);
  OutStream.CopyFrom(InStream, InStream.Size);
  OutStream.Free;
  InStream.Free;
end.
```